# What's wrong with my comparable method? Trying to sort int fields within objects

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting

I want to sort the `Employee` objects by age in ascending order.  I can tell that it's not working because when I print the list using both `Collections.sort` and `Collections.reverse`, the result is the same.  Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
package simplejavaassignment;
import simplejavaassignment.Department.DepartmentType;

//fields
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
    String name;
    int age;
    DepartmentType department;

    public Employee(String name, int age, DepartmentType department)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.department = department;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee compareAge)
    {
        return this.age-compareAge.age;
    }
}
```

and

```
package simplejavaassignment;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import simplejavaassignment.Employee;

public class Department
{
    enum DepartmentType {ACCOUNTING, MARKETING, HUMAN_RESOURCES, INFORMATION_SYSTEMS}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        employeeList.add(new Employee("Counting Guru", 55, DepartmentType.ACCOUNTING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Counting Pro", 45, DepartmentType.ACCOUNTING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Counting Savvy", 40, DepartmentType.ACCOUNTING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Counting Novice", 25, DepartmentType.ACCOUNTING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Sales Guru", 50, DepartmentType.MARKETING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Sales Pro", 48, DepartmentType.MARKETING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Sales Savvy", 38, DepartmentType.MARKETING));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Hiring Guru", 58, DepartmentType.HUMAN_RESOURCES));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Hiring Pro", 47, DepartmentType.HUMAN_RESOURCES));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Hacking Pro", 46, DepartmentType.INFORMATION_SYSTEMS));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Hacking Guru", 51, DepartmentType.INFORMATION_SYSTEMS));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Hacking Savvy", 38, DepartmentType.INFORMATION_SYSTEMS));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Hacking Novice", 23, DepartmentType.INFORMATION_SYSTEMS));

        Collections.sort(employeeList);
        System.out.println(employeeList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. When I run your code, it sorts the list correctly in ascending order of employee age and prints it in that order. You should add a `toString()` method on your Employee class though, so you can actually see what it prints.

P.S. Be aware that subtracting the ints to be compared would not work correctly if the values were extremely large, because the result then would overflow. The best practice would be to replace the subtraction with `Integer.compare(this.age, compareAge.age)`.

P.P.S. In Java 8 or above, the simplest way to do that sort would be to not bother with the compareTo method or Comparable interface, and simply write either:

```
employeeList.sort((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.age, e2.age));
```

or:

```
employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.age));
```

Comment: @zulualph `[23, 25, 38, 38, 40, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 55, 58]`. That's with a simple `toString()` method on the Employee class that just returns the age: `@Override public String toString() { return "" + age; }`

Comment: That's odd - when I add that, I get the same thing, but there's no indication that it works when I run the `Department` class.  I'm a complete beginner and didn't know how to use the `toString()` method.  Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @zulualph Then how did you conclude that the list was not sorted if you couldn't see its contents?

Comment: Well, `Collections.sort` and `Collections.reverse` would give opposite results, right?  When I tried entered both of them separately and ran `Department`, there was no difference in the printed output.  I guess something is fundamentally wrong with my test method.

Comment: So if I were to use this one `employeeList.sort((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.age, e2.age));` is there a different class I need to import?  Where would you suggest I insert this code?  What currently existing code would I omit?

Comment: @zulualph You just put it instead of `Collections.sort(employeeList);` No imports required. You could then, if you wanted, remove the Employee class's `compareTo` method and `implements Comparable`. (They wouldn't be used since the sort call is now supplying its own comparator in the call.) There are other ways to write sorts too, but the two I suggested are the simplest.

Comment: Hm. When I insert that line in place of `Collections.sort(employeeList);`, I get the following errors: e2 cannot be resolved to a variable; Syntax error on token "-", -- expected; e1 cannot be resolved to a variable; e1 cannot be resolved to a variable; Syntax error on token ",", . expected

Comment: @zulualph That means you're not using Java 8.

Comment: Well that's certainly a mystery.  Maybe I haven't chosen Java 8 in Eclipse or something?...not sure, it's the only one on my computer.  This is what the About screen in the Java Control Panel shows: Version 8 Update 5 (build 1.8.0_05-b13). And the only item in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs is jre8.

Comment: @zulualph Only quite recent versions of Eclipse support Java 8 syntax (Eclipse 4.4+, or 4.3 if you install a special patch). It's worth upgrading, because [there's lots of good stuff](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/). It's also possible that your version of Eclipse does support Java 8, but you need to select it in the Eclipse project's settings.

Comment: Oh snap.  That's it. I specifically chose Eclipse Juno because the instructions for this assignment specified it, thought I'm not sure why.  Well we found the problem!  Maybe I'll just disregard the instructions and download the latest version...

Comment: In any case, your assistance is much appreciated.